# How to implement custom timeout for function that connects to server

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, timeout

I want to establish a connection with a b0 client for Coppelia Sim using the Python API. Unfortunately, this connection function does not have a timeout and will run indefinitely if it fails to connect.

To counter that, I tried moving the connection to a separate process (multiprocessing) and check after a couple of seconds, whether the process is still alive. If it still is, I kill the process and continue with the program.

This sort of works, as it does not block my program anymore, however the process does not stop when the connection is successfully made, so it kills the process, even when the connection succeeds.

How can I fix this and also write the b0client to the global variable?

```
def connection_function():
    global b0client
    b0client = b0RemoteApi.RemoteApiClient('b0RemoteApi_pythonClient', 'b0RemoteApi', 60)
    print('Success!')
    return 0


def establish_b0_connection(timeout):
    connection_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=connection_function)
    connection_process.start()

    # Wait for [timeout] seconds or until process finishes
    connection_process.join(timeout=timeout)

    # If thread is still active
    if connection_process.is_alive():
        print('[INITIALIZATION OF B0 API CLIENT FAILED]')

        # Terminate - may not work if process is stuck for good
        connection_process.terminate()

        # OR Kill - will work for sure, no chance for process to finish nicely however
        # connection_process.kill()

        connection_process.join()
        print('[CONTINUING WITHOUT B0 API CLIENT]')
        return False
    else:
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b0client = None
    establish_b0_connection(timeout=5)
    # Continue with the code, with or without connection.
    # ...
```

Comment: To clarify, when the connection succeeds, it actually reaches the print('Success') statement.